# Handling 500 Internal server error using Selenium2Library in Robot

Tags: jquery, robotframework

I am using Robot framework with Selenium2Library to automate my web application and recently while executing my smoke suite I experienced a frequent error that says "Error! The requested URL returned 500 - Internal Server Error" when the test script performing below actions:

1. When the script clicks links like DisableUser, Reset Password etc to open a confirmation dialog box.
2. When the script selects an option from drop down that opens a dialogbox
3. When the script clicks on ExportLink to open the dialog box to save the file etc..

The script throws 'UnExpectedAlertPresentException' for all these above scenarios when the pop up appears with Internal server error...

When I cross verified the same scenario manually i.e. i clicked on a same link to launch a dialog box to disable the user account and got the internal server error popup on top of the Disable user dialog box and when I cicked OK on the error popup, the disable user dialog box still spinning and the fields were not displayed on that dialog.

I would like to know if there is a way to handle this internal server alert popup and proceed further because now the rest of test cases will fail because of not handling this alert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exceptions like this:

[Run Keyword And Ignore Error](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error)

```
${status}            ${value} =                Run Keyword And Ignore Error      Click Link    MyErrorLink
Run Keyword Unless    '${status}' == 'PASS'    Click Link                        CloseDialogue
Run Keyword If        '${status}' == 'PASS'    Click Link                        Proceed
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind remarks, i will extend my answer with some examples.